# Why is this react child component attribute value Undefined?

Tags: reactjs, react-component, react-state

I am learning ReactJS and I am trying to create a simple quiz using react components. I have three components:

**FinalDiv** -- parent component

- **Question**: Displays Question
- **Answer**: Displays options for that question

Both are child component of **FinalDiv**

For calculation of correct and incorrect answer and to move to next question I am using method *processor*.

My problem is that I am unable to get the value of selected option from **Answer** component. Value of option is stored in *capvalue* attribute of **Answer**.

So far, I have tried event.target.value to access that value in *processor* method. But it gives undefined when printing in console.

I have also tried *this.capvalue*. But same result.

Mind that it is giving correct value when printing just before rendering, but when printing in *processor* method it is giving *Undefined* value because of which I am not able to check if selected answer is correct. See 2 comments in code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

const questionBoxStyle = {
backgroundColor : 'cyan',
textAlign : 'center',
width : '30%',
height : '50px',
marginLeft : '35%',
marginTop : '50px',
marginBottom : '50px'
}

const btnBoxStyle = {
backgroundColor : 'orange',
textAlign : 'center',
width : '30%',
height : '50px',
marginLeft : '35%',
}

class Question extends Component {
render() {
    return(
        <div style={this.props.style}>
            What is the capital of {this.props.country} ?
        </div>
    )
}
}

class Answer extends Component {
render() {
    return(
        <button onClick={this.props.doOnClick} style={this.props.style}>
            <h3>{this.props.capvalue}</h3>
        </button>
    )
}
}

class FinalDiv extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
        this.state = {
            oq : [
                {
                    q : 'India',
                    op : ['Delhi','Mumbai','Kolkata','Chennai'],
                    correct : 'Delhi'
                },
                {
                    q : 'USA',
                    op : ['DC','New York','Chicago','LA'],
                    correct : 'DC'
                },
                {
                    q : 'UK',
                    op : ['Plymouth','London','Manchester','Derby'],
                    correct : 'London'
                },
                {
                    q : 'Germany',
                    op : ['Dortmund','Frankfurt','Berlin','Munich'],
                    correct : 'Berlin'
                }
            ],
            correct : 0,
            incorrect : 0,
            currIndex : 0
        }
        this.processor = this.processor.bind(this);

}

processor(event) {
// prints undefined in below line
    console.log('selected: '+event.target.capvalue+' -- actual answer: '+this.state.oq[this.state.currIndex].correct)
    if(this.capvalue === this.state.oq[this.state.currIndex].correct) {
        this.setState({
            correct : this.state.correct+1,
        })
    } else {
        this.setState({
            incorrect : this.state.incorrect+1,
        })
    }
    if(this.state.currIndex === 3) {
        this.setState({
            currIndex : 0
        })
    } else {
        this.setState({
            currIndex : this.state.currIndex+1 
        })
    }
}

render() {
    return(
        <div>
            <Question style={questionBoxStyle} country= 
 {this.state.oq[this.state.currIndex].q}/>
            {
                this.state.oq[this.state.currIndex].op.map((value, index) 
=> {
// if i try to print the value here, it prints correctly
                console.log('current index: '+this.state.currIndex+
' -- correct: '+this.state.correct+' -- incorrect: '+this.state.incorrect)
                   return <Answer key={index} style={btnBoxStyle} 
capvalue={value} doOnClick={this.processor}/>
               })
            }
            <div style={questionBoxStyle}> <h2> Correct : 
{this.state.correct} </h2> </div>
            <div style={questionBoxStyle}> <h2> InCorrect : 
{this.state.incorrect} </h2> </div>
        </div>
    )
}
}

ReactDOM.render(<FinalDiv />, document.getElementById('root'));


serviceWorker.unregister();
```

My guess is that *processor* method is not able to access the *Answer* component's attribute in parent component(FinalDiv). So something needs to be done in child component itself(Answer component), but I don't know what. Do I somehow pass state to Child component or something?

Please let me know if you know additional information or if question formatting is wrong.

I recently got unblocked from asking questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the correct answer from your `Answer` component,

```
<button onClick={e => this.props.doOnClick(this.props.capvalue)} style={this.props.style}>
   <h3>{this.props.capvalue}</h3>
</button>
```

Your `processor` function should be,

```
processor(capvalue) {
    console.log(
      'selected: ' +
        capvalue +
        ' -- actual answer: ' +
        this.state.oq[this.state.currIndex].correct,
    )
    if (capvalue === this.state.oq[this.state.currIndex].correct) {
      this.setState({
        correct: this.state.correct + 1,
      })
    } else {
      this.setState({
        incorrect: this.state.incorrect + 1,
      })
    }
    if (this.state.currIndex === 3) {
      this.setState({
        currIndex: 0,
      })
    } else {
      this.setState({
        currIndex: this.state.currIndex + 1,
      })
    }
  }
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandbox-wmyou?fontsize=14)

Answer (score 1):

The event target is the H3 tag in Answer component and it does not have a property capvalue , therefore, attempt to read

> event.target.capvalue

returns undefined. You just need to change

> event.target.capvalue

to

> event.target.innerHTML

and the code will work as expected. However, this is not best approach to achieve this so you should adopt a different approach.One off the top of my head is assigning unique ids to answers and passing the correct answer's id to Answer as prop.